# Creating right-to-left Excel file from Java

Tags: java, excel, oracle-adf

I use `af:table` component of ADF, and I export table to Excel with `exportCollectionActionListener`.
I get left-t-right file and I try to get right-to-left file.

This is my code:

```xml
<af:exportCollectionActionListener exportedId="dataTable" 
         type="excelHTML" 
         filename="Authorisations.xls"  
         title="Authorisations"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your app set to work in right to left with the right settings in trinidad.xml?
https://adfblog.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/using-arabic-as-locale/

If this doesn't help, you might want to consider using ADF Desktop Integration to create your Excel files directly there accessing your ADF model layer.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index-085534.html